# Find int in a string (char*) in pure c

Tags: c, string, parsing, char, int

There is a string with a line of text. Let's say:

```
char * line = "Foo|bar|Baz|23|25|27";
```

I would have to find the numbers.

I was thinking of something like this:

1. If the given char is a number, let's put it into a temporary char array. (buffer)
2. If the next character is NOT a number, let's make the buffer a new int.

The problem is... how do I find numbers in a string like this?
(I'm not familiar with C99/gcc that much.)

Compiler used: gcc 4.3 (Environment is a Debian Linux *stable*.)

Comment: "strcmp" could do this, with a switch. If the char equals to a number, we go on. But I'm not sure if this is the best way. (Having an own, long function, just to check if a char is a number.) @squiguy - I'll write a short example in a second.

Comment: take a look at isdigit().

Comment: @RandyHoward - And there goes the answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would approach as the following:

- Considering '|' as the separator, tokenize the line of text, i.e. split the line into multiple fields.
- For each token:

  - If the token is numeric:

    - Convert the token to a number

Some library functions that might be useful are `strtok`, `isdigit`, `atoi`.

Answer (score 2):

One possible implementation for the approach suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15774209/1025391), based on [sscanf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void find_integers(const char* p) {
    size_t s = strlen(p)+1;
    char buf[s];
    const char * p_end = p+s;
    int n;
    /* tokenize string */
    for (; p < p_end && sscanf(p, "%[^|]%n", &buf, &n); p += (n+1))
    {
        int x;
        /* try to parse an integer */
        if (sscanf(buf, "%d", &x)) {
            printf("got int :) %d\n", x);
        }
        else {
            printf("got str :( %s\n", buf);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    const char *  line = "Foo|bar|Baz|23|25|27";
    find_integers(line);
}
```

Output:

```
$ gcc test.c && ./a.out 
got str :( Foo
got str :( bar
got str :( Baz
got int :) 23
got int :) 25
got int :) 27
```